# RxJava custom countdowntimer continues to "tick" after disposed

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I made a simple timer class using RxJava Observables:

```
public abstract class CountDownTimer {

    private final TimeUnit timeUnit;  
    private final Long startValue; 
    private Disposable disposable;

    public CountDownTimer(Long startValue, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        this.timeUnit = timeUnit;
        this.startValue = startValue;
    }

    public abstract void onTick(long tickValue);

    public abstract void onFinish();

    public void start(){
        Observable.zip(
                        Observable.range(0, startValue.intValue()), 
                        Observable.interval(1, timeUnit),  
                        (integer, aLong) -> startValue - integer)   
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())  
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())  
                .subscribe(new Observer<Long>() {   
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                        disposable = d;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Long aLong) {
                        onTick(aLong);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        onFinish();
                    }
                });
    }

    public void cancel(){
        if(disposable!=null) {
            disposable.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

I use this class to set progress on a `ProgressBar` (initiation from a method in `Fragment`):

```
timer = new CountDownTimer(QUESTION_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long tickValue) {
            //set progress color
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            //set progress color
        }
    };
    timer.start();
```

When onFinish() tick from timer, onDestroyView from fragment, and other places in my fragment code, I call this:

```
if(timer != null){
        timer.cancel();
    }
```

And I can see from logging that cancel() is called and it is disposed of. However, even when resetting timer (I have a class variable Countdowntimer timer) like I showns in my second code example, I can see that the old timer is still active and updates the progressbar (both the old, and new timer updates the progressbar, so progress jumps between these 2 values).

I don't understand this, why is the timer not completly disposed of? Why does the "old timer" still continue to update the values?

EDIT:

This is how the timer class behaves in a fragment:

```
TICK 25    //first call to create new timer
TICK 24
TICK 23
TICK 22
TICK 21
TIMER CANCELLED    //first call stopped. timer.cancel() called (which then calls disposable.dispose() in CountDownTimer.class)
TICK 25    //second call
TICK 25    // somehow the first call also start again? 
TICK 24
TICK 24
TICK 23
TICK 23
TICK 22
TICK 22
TIMER CANCELLED    //cancel second call
TICK 21    //first or second call still continues
TICK 20
TICK 19
TICK 18
```

And it will continue to "stack on" more timers (which I called dispose() on)...

Comment: In theory, this looks ok. Put a log everywhere and try to see if there are some irregularities there. Could be that you call the cancel before the subscription happens.

Comment: Are you creating a new Countdowntimer or are you reusing a single instance?

Comment: I have a variable in fragment `Countdowntimer timer;` and I set it `timer = new CountDownTimer(...)` several times during when fragment is resumed/started @akarnokd

Comment: Maybe you overwrite the timer with a new instance, then you call cancel which does nothing before the new timer has started. Basically you lost the reference to the old timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you do this in this way, but there is an operator `intervalRange` that gets you this in fewer steps. Also managing the disposable could be a problem if you are reusing the same `Countdowntimer`. Try this:

```java
class CountdownTimer {
    SerialDisposable disposable = new SerialDisposable();

    //...

    public void start() {
         disposable.set(
             Observable.intervalRange(0, startValue, 
                 1, timeUnit, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
             .subscribe(
                 tick -> onTick(startValue - tick)
                 error -> error.printStackTrace()
                 () -> onFinish()
             )
         );
    }

    public void cancel() {
         disposable.set(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't set `disposable.set(null)`. I also can see from logging that my timer keeps ticking after calling dispose. Any idea?

Comment: Please provide a standalone project that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: So I created a simple project with same CountDownTimer -> `https://github.com/aliamid93/CountDownTImer` and I see that it works on that project. However, I do not know the problem with my original project. It is on github -> `https://github.com/aliamid93/Qwez`, you can find the usage of CountDownTimer at `https://github.com/aliamid93/Qwez/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/qwez/ui/question/QuestionsFragment.java` and CountDownTimer at `https://github.com/aliamid93/Qwez/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/qwez/util/CountDownTimer.java`.

Comment: If I can simplify my problem more for easier readability, please let me know.

Comment: Is there a way I could debug Qwez? I can't get past the login screen. Placing breakpoints onto the onQuestion and disposeOfTimer should reveal where things go wrong.

Comment: I created test login `user: debug@debug.com and pass: HelloSir=123` or you can also create user accounts from the app

Comment: What I could decipher is that `onQuestion` gets called twice after the first question, thus you have two timers starting. I don't understand where this call comes from. For the second question, there are two trigger for `updateQuestion` due to `getSingleGameAndQuestionsInteractor.getGameQuestions(gameId)`.

Comment: I can't figure out why. It also keeps on adding. I can see that  `getSingleGameAndQuestionsInteractor.getGameQuestions(gameId)` gets triggered once, then twice, then three times, four times, etc when you keep clicking "nextQuestion" etc. Any ideas?

Comment: What is its data source? Do you feed that data source when a question gets answered? Maybe you update the question with an answer and the database signals this change over again.

Comment: Datasource is local database (SqLite/Room). I update a particular question in viewmodel at `nextQuestion()` and recieve updates from `getSingleGameAndQuestionsInteractor.getGameQuestions(gameId)` which gets triggered everytime its updated, but it is also triggered again/twice for old questions. I do not understand why, can't figure it out.

Comment: Thank you again for all the help. With your comments I managed to find the actual fault. I'm awarding you the bounty for your comment about it getting triggered twice(problem was that I  was updated both entities from my nested object and thus triggering my nested class flowable twice, so it was error from my design) & simplification of my timer with intervalRange(). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the instance through GC too. add the following to all the places where you are calling `timer.cancel()`. Setting it to null will notify the GC that the timer instance is ready to be cleared.

```
if(timer != null) {
   timer.cancel();
   timer= null;
}
```

Comment: If that's the problem I'd be *very* surprised.

Comment: I tried this but doesnt change anything for me. I also can see from logging that my timer keeps ticking after calling dispose. Any idea?